# How to make a subroutine in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, subroutine, groupbox

So I recently took it upon myself to make a little program to make my job little easier. However, much of the code is repetitive, so was wondering if there is a way to make this easier.
Below is the code I repeat 46 times and a few variables change each time, like the GroupBox goes from 1-46, ComboBox goes from 1-46, then at the end I want to uncheck all RadioButtons in that GroupBox also.
Here it is for the first GroupBox:

```
Private Sub Room105()
    Dim rb = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().
                       SingleOrDefault(Function(radiobutton) radiobutton.Checked)
    Dim value = If(CStr(rb?.Tag), ComboBox1.Text = V1)
    If rb?.Tag Is Nothing Then ComboBox1.Text = V1
    If ComboBox1.Text = M1 Then
        ListView1.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            ListView4.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = M2 Then
        ListView2.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            ListView4.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = M3 Then
        ListView3.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            ListView4.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = V1 Then
        RadioButton1.Checked = False
        RadioButton2.Checked = False
        RadioButton3.Checked = False
        ListView5.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.Add("Vacant")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify this function to have the GroupBox control (and others) as arguments to that function:

```
Private Sub Room105(grpBox As GroupBox, comboBx As ComboBox, lv1 As ListView, lv2 As ListView, lv3 As ListView, lv4 As ListView, lv5 As ListView, rb1 As RadioButton, rb2 As RadioButton, rb3 As RadioButton)
    Dim rb = grpBox.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().
                   SingleOrDefault(Function(radiobutton) radiobutton.Checked)

    Dim value = If(CStr(rb?.Tag), comboBx.Text = V1)
    If rb?.Tag Is Nothing Then comboBx.Text = V1
    If comboBx.Text = M1 Then
        lv1.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            ListView4.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf comboBx.Text = M2 Then
        lv2.Items.Add(GroupBox1?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            lv4.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf comboBx.Text = M3 Then
        lv3.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.Add(value)
        If rb?.Tag = CO Then
            lv4.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.add(value)
        End If
    ElseIf comboBx.Text = V1 Then
        rb1.Checked = False
        rb2.Checked = False
        rb3.Checked = False
        lv5.Items.Add(grpBox?.Tag).SubItems.Add("Vacant")
    End If
End Sub
```

You would then call this function as many times as you need, switching out the different sets of controls as needed:

```
Room105(GroupBox1, ComboBox1, ListView1, ListView2, ListView3, ListView4, ListView5, RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3)
```

PS: I highly recommend giving this controls more descriptive names than what you are using here.

Answer (score 0):

Surely. If you create an array for group boxes and another one for combo boxes, put the objects there, then you can loop through your array and do what needs to be done and then instead of the hard-coded values you could use your array at the current index.